# Swagger UI same schema name after inheriting

Tags: swagger-ui, swagger-editor

I went to this [swagger editor](http://editor.swagger.io/) and looked into their example.

I wanted to try extending a model.
In the example there, they have:

```
Tag:
  type: "object"
  properties:
    id:
      type: "integer"
      format: "int64"
    name:
      type: "string"
  xml:
    name: "Tag"
```

So I added my Tag2:

```
  Tag2:
    allOf:
      - $ref: '#/definitions/Tag'
      - properties:
        prop: 
          type: "string"
```

My new model does appear in the Models List, but instead of having the 2 schema names (Tag and Tag2), I have two Tag entries. One of them correctly has the new 'prop' field.

How can I make the second one to appear with the correct name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in Swagger Editor. It's being tracked in:
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-editor/issues/1288

and is caused by
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-js/issues/1024